# updating state value doesnt work in react with increment operator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-state

I was trying to simply update my state by incrementing it, but for some reason it dosnt seems to be updating with the increment operator, which is very strange to me.

Im using following code snippet

```
  var [counter, setstate] = useState(1);

  const clickHandle = () => {

    setstate(counter ++);  //doesn't work
   // setState(counter + 1); // Does work
  };
```

Same goes with the following code snippet.

```
  var [counter, setstate] = useState(1);

  const clickHandle = () => {
    setstate((previousValue) => {
      return previousValue + previousValue ; //does work (keeps doubling the value as expected)
     // return previousValue ++ ;  // doesn't work    
     });   
  };
```

I don't understand why does react behave like this.

Comment: It's not react's behaviour .it's the `previousvalue++` behaviour which returns first and then updates the variable.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a react thing. what you want is `++counter` and not `counter++`. the latter returns the value before incrementing, so you're practically setting it to the same state every time. see documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment)

`setState(previousValue => ++previousValue)` would work just fine, but of course `setState(++count)` still wouldn't work because you're mutating a `const` and not the copy that react provides in the callback function's argument