# react UseState problem One code is working but another is not working

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

**The above code is not working as expected**

```
import { useState } from "react";
function App() {
  let [Counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  const increaseCounter = () => {
    console.log(Counter, Math.random());
    setCounter(Counter++);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <h1>{Counter}</h1>
      <button onClick={increaseCounter}>++</button>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**The following code works as expected**

```
import { useState } from "react";
function App() {
  let [Counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  const increaseCounter = () => {
    console.log(Counter, Math.random());
    setCounter(Counter+1);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <h1>{Counter}</h1>
      <button onClick={increaseCounter}>++</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

**just out of curosity can anyone explain me**

Want to understand behavior of UseState in react I have written two seperate code block expecting same behavior but both of the code is working diffrently can someone explain me

Comment: This isn't related to useState or React. It's how `++` (postfix) works. `x++` will increment `x` but will return the original value of `x`, whereas `x+1` returns the incremented value. `++x` would achieve something similar to `x+1` (but then you're technically mutating state, which isn't recommended)

Comment: or rather: [updating state value doesnt work in react with increment operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69183464)

Comment: Basic gist is that the first one mutates the state reference, a huge React anti-pattern, while the second takes the current state value closed over in callback scope and returns the result of adding 1 to it.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a useState problem but this implementation of yours is wrong

```
setCounter(Counter++);
```

You are using a postfix operator which updates after the function is completed

```
let cnt = 1
console.log(cnt++)
// 1
console.log(cnt)
//2
```

Do you get the logic here? You are updating after useState has set with previous value and similar if you do

```
++counter
```

It will be updated correctly.

Answer (score 0):

When the operator (+,-) is behind the variable, it first returns the original value and then changes it. An your `setCounter` just captures whatever returned first.

So that's why it doesn't work in the first example,

If you really want to use the operators, put them at the beginning of your variable like `++Counter`